# django admin add representational id field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to add a readonly (representational) id field to the django admin change form (view), for example I have this model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def display_id(self):
        # represent the AutoField (id) as "0001"

        return str(self.id).zfill(4)


class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    display_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=ReadOnlyWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooAdminForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name',)}),
        ('Extra info', {'fields': [
            ('display_id',),
        ]}),
    )
```

There's a few problems and nonos here:

- AutoFields aren't available on the form (for good reason), so how do I get the id to display correctly
- Unsaved instances do not have an id to rely on, I would like to display "n/a" when adding a new entry
- I do **not** want to add a display_id field to my model

I tried:

- Overriding the (model)form's init but that tends to get really complex

Should/Can I:

- Fix this behaviour in my `ReadOnlyWidget` somehow?
- Just use a regular `Form` instead of a `ModelForm` to avoid data/form clashes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add readonly_fields to your FooAdmin:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooAdminForm
    readonly_fields('id',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name',)}),
        ('Extra info', {'fields': [
            ('display_id',),
        ]}),
    )
```

Comment: That's not going to work, display_id is a property, also 'id' is an AutoField so it isn't available on the ModelForm